# Is there a way to use a variable offset in assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, addressing-mode

Trying to shortcut the main part of a palindrome checking program see below:

li $t9, $t6($t5)

bne $t9, $t7($t5), no1

This throws a syntax error, is there not a way to use a variable as an offset in assembly? Using PLP software tool 5.2

Comment: In MIPS, no, only for floating-point load/store (in some later MIPS revisions).  I assume this is MIPS?  Also, perhaps you mean `lw` not `li`?  And `bne` can never compare a memory operand; MIPS is a load-store machine (the only instructions that access memory are loads and stores, not memory operands for other instructions)

Comment: yes it is MIPS, thanks

Comment: To actually optimize your code, use pointer increments / decrements instead of actually adding to an array base address every iteration.  e.g. `do { p++; q--; } while(p<q && *p == *q);` or something like that.